# Remove and Install Image Transfer Unit (ITU) in a Lexmark CS410dn

Tags: laser-printer, lexmark-printer

Does anyone know how to remove and install the *Image Transfer Unit* (*ITU*) in a **Lexmark CS410dn**?

I looked and cannot find a way to remove it without disassembling the entire printer.  Also, I contacted Lexmark and they have the documentation but they only give it to the certified technicians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that *is* a user-replaceable part.

Found a [video on Lexmark's site](http://infoserve.lexmark.com/idv/product_videos_id0.html?prod=CS31x_41x_51x$lang=en_US$chk=d1200) showing how to replace it.

Basic steps covered in video:

1. Remove the used imaging kit from the printer
2. Unpack the new imaging unit
3. Unpack the developer units
4. Insert the developer units
5. Remove the additional packaging
6. Insert the new imaging unit
7. Return the used imaging unit to Lexmark for recycling

Answer (score 2):

[According to Lexmark](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=EN&page=content&id=SO7193) it's a user replaceable part.  No tools required!

1. Remove the waste toner bottle
2. Remove all four toner cartridges
3. Lift up the two blue levers and pull open the imaging kit
4. This will reveal a new blue lever, which you push down, then hold the green handles to remove the imaging kit

[image]